# Using Recursion to determine if input is prime

Tags: java, recursion

Ive tried to search for similar questions to see if the answer might be on this site to no avail.
Im currently trying to write a program that determines if the user input is a prime number using a recursive method. The problem is it will not compile do to the variable "n" already being defined in the scope. I dont quite see what the compiler means. 
Heres is my code

```
/**
 * Created on 3/26/2017.
 **/
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeNumberRecursion {
    public static void main(String[] n) {
        //Variables declared
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        int div = 2;
        //Program is introduced
        System.out.println(" Prime Number Recursion Program");
        System.out.println("*********************************");
        //User is prompted for a number
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        n = userInput.nextInt();
        //Conditional statement prints result
        if(isPrime(n,div) == 1){System.out.println(n +" is a prime number");}
        else{System.out.println(n +" is not a prime number");}
    }
    //User input is passed to isPrime recursive method
    public static int isPrime(int n, int div) {
        if(n == 1) {return 1;}
        else if(n % div == 0) {return -1;}
        else if(n == div) {return -1;}
        else{return isPrime(n, ++div);}
    }
}
```

Comment: change the name of the variable n, you are using it twice. The argument for the main method as a string and as an int variable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if `isPrime` returned a `boolean`?  Returning 1 or -1 is not very descriptive.

Comment: Yeah it would be better code for sure. But I usually go in and change that kind of stuff after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'n' is a duplicate variable. You are using it both at `int n;` and `String[] n` Rename `String [] n` to n1 or something

Comment: No worries. If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it

Comment: Would you happen to also know whats wrong with my logic for determining the prime value? I seem to have a problem with my logic.

Comment: I can see 2 problems prima facia. 1) Your program will return 1 as prime number which is incorrect. 2) You are increasing div and eventually it will become equal to n(provided n > 2). so  else if(n == div) {return -1;} will be executed and -1 would be returned. Anyways thats a separate question

Comment: Ah I see. Right you are. Forgot to change that. Thanks for the insight. Sorry to the mods if I did anything incorrectly while asking. Still very new and am trying to be self-sufficient.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com :)

Answer (score 0):

If you start at 2 you only need to check up to the square root of n for better efficiency. Also as already stated any number below 2 is not prime.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n, int div) {
    if ( n < 2 || Math.sqrt(n) > div) {
        return false;
    } else if (n % div == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return isPrime(n, ++div);
    }
}
```

Comment: For even better efficiency, don't recompute `sqrt(n)` over and over.  By the way, these are valid points but they are not answers to the question.